# Installing TensorFlow with pipenv gives error

Tags: python, tensorflow, pipenv

I'm trying to install **TensorFlow** using **pipenv**.

This is my Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
pylint = "*"

[packages]
python-telegram-bot = "*"
imdbpy = "*"
matplotlib = "*"
scikit-image = "*"
scikit-learn = "*"
tensorflow = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

I then run:

```
pipenv install tensorflow
```

Which outputs:

```
Installing tensorflow…
Adding tensorflow to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (989c3d) out of date, updating to (0d6760)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Success!
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Locking Failed!
```

Followed by a big traceback that ends with:

```
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyh639mq4build\functools32\
```

My virtual environment uses **Python 3.8.0 64 bit**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Offical tensorflow system requirements say: "Python 3.4–3.7"

Answer (score 5):

As the comments pointed out, Tensorflow only supports up to python 3.7 (as March 2020). You can find more info in the [system requirements page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) of the documentation.

So, to fix your issue:

1. Remove the virtual environment with `pipenv --rm`
2. Remove the Pipfile.lock
3. Change the last lines of your Pipfile to

   ```
   [requires]
   python_version = "3.7"
   ```
4. Run `pipenv install --dev` to recreate the environment again and `pipenv install tensorflow` to install tensorflow

Done!